# creating initial data entries and flushing before each test lettuce django

Tags: python, django, lettuce

I am a novice to using lettuce for BDD development in Django however, I need help in figuring out how i can load initial test data for my models and also how to flush them before each test.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest starting point is to look at http://lettuce.it/tutorial/tables.html. For "flushing" data, I use a `terrain.py` with code like the following:

```
from django.db import transaction

@before.each_feature
def begin_transaction(feature):
    #shouldn't strictly be needed, but I've gotten
    #inconsistent results without it
    transaction.rollback()
    transaction.set_autocommit(False)


@after.each_feature
def end_transaction(feature):
    transaction.rollback()
```

It may be more appropriate to use `before.each_scenario`. Use what works for you.

Comment: transaction.set_autocommit isn't available on Django 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following:

```
@before.each_scenario
def load_scenario_fixture(scenario):
    call_command('loaddata', 'lettuce_global', interactive=False, verbosity=0)
    fixture_path = os.path.join(scenario.feature.name.lower().replace(' ', '_'), scenario.name.lower().replace(' ', '_'))
    logger.info("Loading fixture:")
    logger.info("  " + fixture_path)
    call_command('loaddata', fixture_path, interactive=False, verbosity=0)

@after.each_scenario
def flush_database(scenario):
    logger.info("Flushing the test database ...")
    call_command('flush', interactive=False, verbosity=0)
```

This loads in a global test fixture before each scenario and also a specific fixture for the scenario. The fixture file paths are in the format {app}/fixtures/{feature name}/{fixture name}
After the scenario is complete I simply use the Django flush command to reset.